# Modal confirm delete - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel project and I have a "bug" when I attempt to delete a city from the database.

When I press the Delete button, the first thing what needs to happen is opening a modal where I need to confirm the delete or cancel it.

My problem: when I press the Delete button, the modal opens, but the form goes on forward without waiting for confirmation.

[image]

Script:

```
$('#confirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');

    $(this).find('.modal-body p').text($message);

    $title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');

    $(this).find('.modal-title').text($title);

    // Pass form reference to modal for submission on yes/ok

    var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');

    $(this).find('.modal-footer #confirm').data('form', form);

});

<!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
$('#confirmDelete').find('.modal-footer #confirm').on('click', function(){

    $(this).data('form').submit();

});
```

Button:

```
<div class="col-md-4">

{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','action' => ['AdminController@brisanjegrada', $gradovi->id],'style' => 'display:inline']) !!}

{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash">Obrišite Grad</i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',' data-toggle'=>'modal','data-target'=>'#confirmDelete','data-title'=>'Brisanje županije','data-message'=>'Da li ste sigurni da želite obrisati grad'] )  }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Natrag</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Obriši</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: replace type=submit with type=button

Comment: what's that code in Button? Blade? Anyways, In your javascript you could bind it directly with  `$("#confirm").click()` . Also I didn't know that `show.bs.modal` was a event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Button type to button instead of submit. 
'type' => 'button'